# Dynamic Update MySql Table

Tags: php, mysql

I am attempting  to Dynamically update a MySql table, the `$query` looks correct when i echo it, but for some reason it dose not work when i insert the code into the MySql Query.

```
$b = 1;
$query_a = array();
$vars = array();
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM my_table");

for ($i = 0; $i < mysql_num_fields($result); $i++) {
    $vars[] = mysql_field_name($result,$b);
    $b++;
}



foreach ($vars as $v)
{
    if (isset($_GET[$v]))
    {
        $isclean =  $_GET[$v];
        $query[] = $v.' = '.$isclean.'';
    }
}
$query = implode(',', $query);


mysql_query("UPDATE my_table SET $query WHERE UIN = '1'");
```

Comment: what error does it give?

Comment: make echo mysql_error(); if there's something wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing your data types, my guess is it's because you're not adding single quotes around your values. You probably want something like:

```
$query[] = $v.' = \''.$isclean.'\'';
```